# How to correctly configure multi-services docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, spring-cloud, boot2docker

I have Docker with version `1.13.1` on Windows. And next configuration for compose:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  discovery:
    build: ../discovery
    ports:
     - 8761:8761

  gateway:
    build: ../gateway
    ports:
     - 8888:8888
```

My gateway service tried to lookup discovery service by `localhost:8761`, but it failed.

I tried to set `discovery:8761` but it also failed.
It works only with IP from `DOCKER_HOST` property.
I forwarded ports `8761` from VB image to `localhost`, and it available on `localhost:8761` from windows.

How to correctly configure multi-services docker-compose and domain names without hard coded ips in services?

Comment: Your approach of using the service name when inside the container network (`discovery:8761`) should be correct. Can you elaborate on how it is failing?

Comment: It was an error: Connection refused (Connection refused). But now I have tried with `discovery:8761` and command `docker-compose up --build` and all works fine. Just missed `--build`. Thank you!

Comment: Glad you were able to fix it. I suggest moving to version 3.3 of Compose instead of 2.1. It comes with the latest docker 17.06CE which is available and stable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you fixed it, my two cents: maybe you should force a startup order in docker-compose.yml, following: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on